Are there any one-word idioms?
Definition 1. An idiom is a group of words established by usage as having a meaning not deducible from those of the individual words.
Definition 2. An idiom is a phrase or expression that has a figurative or non-literal meaning that's different from the literal meaning of the individual words.
I have this minor, intrusive thought about when we might be able to say that an single word is an idiom all by itself according to these two definitions.
I've included my attempt at answering my own question as an answer below.

This has been discussed on English SE:"I would say that interjections like "dope!", "lit!", "sick!" are expressions with idiomatic meanings, but they are not idioms and in fact single words cannot be idioms."

I’m voting to close this question because it is a question about linguistic usage with no relation whatsoever to philosophy.

In addition to other comments, I don't think linguistics generally considers "word" a fundamental thing across different languages. "Morpheme" might be more fundamental

Conifold, as usual, is spot on. An idiom is when two or more words are used in a way inconsistent with their literal meaning by definition. There's no philosophical dispute here; it's a technical definition from linguistics. Lexemes can develop new senses, and in fact, it's difficult, with the exception of core words that are used so heavily, they maintain their meaning over millennia, such as Dolgopolsky's list.

@Kaia That's a good point. Lexemes are actually fundamental, but they are not the basic unit of semantics because they are composed of morphemes. According to linguists, stereotypical idioms must be phrasemes.

Here's my attempt at answering my own question.
Suppose we accept Definition 1. It is essentially saying that, assuming we're given the definitions of the individual words in the collection of words, we can't determine the meaning of the entire collection and the meaning of the entire collection is determined by usage. We might say the following:
Definition 1*. A collection of words is an idiom when, if we're given the meaning of the individual words in a collection of words, then we can't deduce the meaning of the entire collection, and the meaning of the entire collection is determined by usage.
So, if we don't know the meaning of a word, it's automatically an idiom since the antecedent is false and the consequent is true because one cannot determine what a word means by hearing just that word and because we can say that the meaning of the word is determined by usage thanks to Wittgenstein.
On the other hand, if we do know the meaning of a word, then we are able to deduce the meaning of the whole collection because it's just that word. The antecedent is true and the consequent is false. Thus, it is not an idiom here.
Suppose we accept Definition 2. In this case, it seems clear that if a collection of words has only one word, the meaning of the one individual word in the collection is the same as the meaning of the whole collection, whether it's figurative/non-literal or not. Therefore, there are no one-word idioms according to this definition.

"If we don't know the meaning of a word, it's automatically an idiom since the antecedent is false and the consequent is true". In natural language, if-then is not necessarily interpreted as the material conditional, most speakers would not consider a word to be an idiom simply because they do not know what it means. And it is not true that the literal meaning of a word always determines what it means when used, it may well be used non-literally, although linguists still tend not to label it "idiom" in such cases. "Metaphor" is more common.

+1 because you put some real thought into this, but instead of speculating, you can simply look at how linguists treat the matter. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiom

There may be many in other languages.
'Rip Van Winkle' functions as a single word, even if it is not a single word. 'Utopian' can be treated as a one-word idiom.
Names of famous movies, books or characters (Eg. Dectators) may be functioning as idioms in most languages.
